# aspnet_regiis unable to decrypt the Web.config

Tags: encryption, web-config, rsa

I encrypt ConnectionStrings section in the web.config file successfully by the following command:

> aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "[web.config physical path]"
>   -prov "[provider name]"

But when I decrypt it by the following command:

> aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "[web.config physical path]"

I encounter the failed decryption message:

**Failed to decrypt using provider '[provider name]'. Error message from the provider: The parameter is incorrect.
 ([web.config path] line 54)**

**The parameter is incorrect.**

As a reminder:
Encryption and decryption action are on the same machine.